# WPF: possible to apply Style to all items in a StackPanel regardless of their type

Tags: wpf, styles, wpf-controls

If the StackPanel contains controls of several types (e.g. ComboBox, CheckBox, Grid), when applying margin or padding styles, is it possible in XAML to express the concept "all of the items you contain" or "each of the items your contain" and apply the style to the StackPanel itself, or must each control be explicity referenced by its type as below?  Is there a way to say TargetType=ANY?

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type foo:ComboBox}">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
     </Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type foo:CheckBox}">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
     </Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type foo:GridView}">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
     </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Comment: yes, target the style to a base type, such as control

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ComboBox />
    <Label />
    <ListView />
```

Comment: Does `{x:Type Control}` not include third-party custom controls?  The approach above doesn't seem to work with them.

Comment: It should, I use telerik quite a bit and that approach works, as even there RadRadioButton is derived from RadioButton, which is derived from Button, then Control... However, that probably doesn't help you. So I would suggest, first look at that 3rd party lib in your object browser and figure out what their base types are

Comment: Interesting. I'm using latest Telerik WPF controls. Can't seem to get it to work. I have a RadProgressBar and a GridViewDataControl in a StackPanel in the left pane of a RadDocking container. The RadProgressBar is in Telerik.Windows.Controls; BaseTypes: RangeBase -> Control -> FrameworkElement.

Comment: do your other controls have styles on them? if so, then in order for them to pick the style in this sample, you will have to base them off this style. You'll have to give this style a x:Key="whateverName" then in your styles specify BasedOn="{StaticResource whateverName}"

Comment: try using a namespace that you are referencing in XAML in order use your telerik controls. Assumeing that you use x:telerik ....in declaration : TargetType="telerik:Control"

Comment: and another thought, give this style a x:Key then use it on each control explicitly. Style={StaticResource myStyle}, or basedon="{StaticResource myStle}"

Comment: In the right pane's StackPanel, I've styled the controls by referencing their Telerik types, e.g. `<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadComboBox}">`.  The left pane's StackPanel contains only the RadProgressBar and the GridViewDataControl. In this test, I'm trying to set the margin on the controls in the left pane only, using your suggested approach.  Will the individually applied styles in the right pane conflict with the TargetType=Control approach in the left pane? I was assuming that each StackPanel would have its own style-scope.

Comment: well, that's the dilemma... you want to base your styles off more generic ones, and in "child" styles set additional differences. But then there might be the point where you're specifying a style for each control and not reusing it else where, so the question becomes, why even create styles.

Comment: on the other note, I for sure remember targeting a button with a style, where the foreground is white. Then spinning wheels trying to figure out why in the hell my RadCalendar control's days/hours are not visible. Turned out that they are Buttons, so I know for sure that telerik controls definitely respond to styles targeting generic controls...